# switching between textboxes with 1 button

Tags: vb.net

context: im making a dice game, the goal is that i enter the number of throws i want ( of 2 dices at a time) when i click the button for the first time 2 dices are rolled and the total and the image of the dices that were rolled is displayed under player 1 when i click it a second time same thing but under player 2... so on until the players have both rolled the number of times i entered. 
https://gyazo.com/798aa46eb1eff6419811da7ca7ac8f9e link to what it looks like

problem : i dont know how to seperate the two and have 2 different totals. my idea was to somehow count the number of times the user presses the button and make it so i can set a limit (times) and use it to switch betweens textboxes, i just dont know how. thank you in advance for the help.

```
Picmain1.Visible = True
    Picmain2.Visible = True
    Picdice1.Image = Nothing
    Picdice1_2.Image = Nothing
    Picdice2.Image = Nothing
    Picdice2_2.Image = Nothing
    picdice3.Image = Nothing
    picdice3_2.Image = Nothing
    picdice4.Image = Nothing
    picdice4_2.Image = Nothing
    picdice5.Image = Nothing
    picdice5_2.Image = Nothing
    picdice6.Image = Nothing
    picdice6_2.Image = Nothing
    Integer.TryParse(NumericUpDown1.Text, fois)
    nombre_aleatoire = MyRandomNumber.Next(1, 6)
        nombre_aleatoire2 = MyRandomNumber.Next(1, 6)
        TextBox1.Text &= Environment.NewLine & "ce jeu : " & total()
        total1 += total()
        lbltotal1.Text = "votre total est de :" & total1
        Select Case nombre_aleatoire
            Case 1
                Picmain1.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-1.png")
            Case 2
                Picmain1.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-2-md.png")
            Case 3
                Picmain1.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-3-md.png")
            Case 4
                Picmain1.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-4.png")
            Case 5
                Picmain1.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-5.png")
            Case 6
                Picmain1.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-6.png")
        End Select
        REM multilinetextbox 2
        nombre_aleatoire = MyRandomNumber.Next(1, 6)
    nombre_aleatoire2 = MyRandomNumber.Next(1, 6)
    Select Case nombre_aleatoire2
        Case 1
            Picmain2.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-1.png")
        Case 2
            Picmain2.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-2-md.png")
        Case 3
            Picmain2.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-3-md.png")
        Case 4
            Picmain2.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-4.png")
        Case 5
            Picmain2.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-5.png")
        Case 6
            Picmain2.Load("F:\new documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mi-session\mi-session\Resources\dice-6.png")
    End Select
    TextBox2.Text &= Environment.NewLine & "ce jeu : " & total()
    total2 += total()
    Lbltotal2.Text = "votre total est de :" & total2
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable and switch it each time like so..

```
Private _Player as byte = 1

...In your button click

IF _Player = 1 THEN 
    Textbox1.Text = [Something]
    _Player = 2
else 
    Textbox2.Text = [Something]
    _Player = 1
End if
```

Or if you are going to track the number of rolls anyway, you can use the `MOD` operator:

```
Private _Rolls as int32 = 0

...In your button click

_Rolls += 1
If _Rolls mod 2 = 1 then
    Textbox1.Text = [Something]
else 
    Textbox2.Text = [Something]
End if
```

Comment: Thank you that solves my switching problem very well! i still have the problem that the total and images are always the same for player 2... any idea how to fix that?